# Robot Framework import library instance does not contain defined methods

Tags: python, object, import, robotframework, class-method

I have written a test case in `Robot Framework` which creates an instance of a class in the middle of `Test Suite` using `Builtin.Import_Library` keyword, then calls its methods using `Builtin.Call_Method`:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource            MyKeywords.robot
Test Suite          Initiate My Test


*** Keywords ***
Initiate My Test
    ${ip} =     SET VARIABLE     localhost
    ${port} =   SET VARIABLE     2020
    IMPORT LIBRARY      src/Interface/Utility/WebServiceUtil.py
    ...             ws_ip=${ip}     ws_port=${port}     WITH NAME   webserviceutil


*** Test Cases ***
Test Report A
    ${result} =     CALL METHOD     webserviceutil      get_report_a
    LOG    Result: ${result}        console=${TRUE}
```

File `src/Interface/Utility/WebServiceUtil.py` contains:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import json
from robot.api import logger


class WebServiceUtil(object):

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'

    def __init__(self, ws_ip, ws_port):
        self.reporter_a = ReportA(ip=ws_ip, port=ws_port)
        self.reporter_b = ReportB(ip=ws_ip, port=ws_port)
        self.reporter_c = ReportC(ip=ws_ip, port=ws_port)
        logger.console('>> ZiZi >> webserviceutil has been initialized successfully!')
        logger.console('>> ZiZi >> self.__dict__: ' + str(self.__dict__))
        logger.console('>> ZiZi >> dir(self): ' + str(dir(self)))

    def get_report_a(self):
        return self.reporter_a.get_report()

    def get_report_b(self):
        return self.reporter_b.get_report()

    def get_report_c(self):
        return self.reporter_c.get_report()


class Report(object):

    def get_report():
        return 'This is abstract class!'


class ReportA(Report):

    def get_report():
        return 'This is class A!'


class ReportB(Report):

    def get_report():
    return 'This is class B!'


class ReportC(Report):

    def get_report():
    return 'This is class C!'
```

I get this error in test execution:

```
Object 'webserviceutil' does not have method 'get_sponsor_report'.
```

The `console` prints which I have put in the `__init__` of class `WebServiceUtil` returns:

```
>> ZiZi >> webserviceutil has been initialized successfully!

>> ZiZi >> self.__dict__: {'reporter_a': <WebServiceUtil.ReportA object at 0x7fc18d96a8d0>, 'reporter_b': <WebServiceUtil.ReportB object at 0x7fc18d96abd0>, 'reporter_c': <WebServiceUtil.ReportC object at 0x7fc18d96a910>}

>> ZiZi >> dir(self): ['ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'get_report_a', 'get_report_b', 'get_report_c', 'reporter_a', 'reporter_b', 'reporter_c']
```

As you can see, class methods are listed in the output of `dir()`, but not shown in the output of `self.__dict__`.

I also tried changing `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE` to `GLOBAL`, but it didn't change anything.

Any idea what is the cause?

**EDIT 1:**

I also tried calling `__init__` method of `super` class in the beginning of method `__init__` of class `WebServiceUtil`:

```
super(WebServiceUtil, self).__init__()
```

Same results.

**EDIT 2:**

I tried calling `WebServiceUtil` methods without `CALL METHOD` as @Bryan said with two approaches:

1. `${result} =     webserviceutil      get_report_a`
2. `${result} =     get_report_a`

The first one returned `No keyword with name 'webserviceutil.get_report_a' found.` and the second returned `No keyword with name 'get_report_a' found.`.

**EDIT 3:**

There are two things that seems to be creating the issue in my mind:

1. I have overwritten `__init__` method.
2. Methods aren't static methods.

I have used classes in `Robot Framework` before and none of them had above specs; so, I guess maybe these are making the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the question edits, the issue was related to the overwritten `__init__` method and used my class variables in other ways. I don't know why, but removing `__init__` solved the problem. Methods are still class methods; which means both static and class methods are treated the same here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing it, the methods  become keywords. You don't need to use `call method`. In your example, when you import `WebServiceUtil`, you have access to keywords named `get report A`, `get report B`, and `get report C`.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Report A
    ${result} =     get report A
    LOG    Result: ${result}        console=${TRUE}
```

Comment: additional note: as stated in docs for IMPORT LIBRARY, this KW should be used for dynamic loading libs in case libs are not available before robot execution. In other case, it is better to explicitly import libs in ***Settings *** section with Library  <path_to_lib>.  Lib imported by IMPORT LIBRARY, is visible across whole suite file just like Import from Settings

Comment: @jozefow, class is present before test execution, but it's parameters should be extracted from a config file; they are not constants which I can use explicitly.

Comment: @Bryan, I used `get report A` in two ways; no hope. Please review my edits.